# Rails: send_data(csv) putting object id in csv file rather than csv info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a block in a rails controller that looks like this:

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ["Name", "Other Field"]
  csv << [@app.name, @app.other_field]
  send_data csv, filename: 'test.csv'
end
```

But then the contents of the downloaded file are simply this:

```
#<CSV:0x007fe518414bc8>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`CSV.generate`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate) returns the generated CSV string, for example:

```
str = CSV.generate { |csv| csv << %w[a b c]; csv << [1,2,3] }
puts str
```

gives you:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
```

as output.

You're passing a `CSV` instance to `send_data` and it is trying to convert that `CSV` instance to a string by, apparently, calling `to_s` on it.

You want to say something more like this:

```
csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ["Name", "Other Field"]
  csv << [@app.name, @app.other_field]
end
send_data csv_string, filename: 'test.csv'
```